# Chrome.exe does not open with Process.Start after upgrading to 64-bit

Tags: c#, google-chrome

So I have been opening chrome with:

```
 Process.Start("chrome.exe","someUrl");
```

It worked and now suddenly get this error:
The system cannot find the file specified

Although

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe","someUrl");
```

works fine.

Comment: What happened to Chrome? Upgrade? Moved? Reinstalled?

Comment: uhm, upgraded to 64 bit..

Comment: 64bit chrome might have a different `.exe` name?

Comment: no.. if I go look under processes it still shows chrome.exe ...

Comment: It may not be in the PATH environment variable anymore.

Comment: Try without extension. It might work for you.

Comment: I have added chrome.exe location to PATH variable.. still the same..

Comment: press (win + R) keys to display the 'run' dialog box, then type chrome then press enter. is it running now? if yes, restart your IDE.

Comment: use ProcessMonitor to see where it's looking for chrome.exe

Comment: @houssam no it does not run